# How to make scrollable modal if there is a form inside it?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a scrollable modal but it doesn't scrollable if I put a form inside it, how to make it scrollable?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="assignModal" data-coreui-backdrop="static" data-coreui-keyboard="false" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <form id="form-assignModal" method="post" autocomplete="off" novalidate="novalidate">
                            <div class="modal-header bg-warning">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Ticket assignment</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="input-assignment_to">Assign to</label>
                                    <select class="form-control select2-single" id="assignment_to" name="assignment_to" data-placeholder="Select an user" required></select>
                                </div>
                                ...
                   </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me (default bootstrap scrolling modal):

```
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalScrollableTitle">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body"><form id="form-assignModal" method="post" autocomplete="off" novalidate="novalidate">
             <div class="modal-header bg-warning">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Ticket assignment</h5>
             </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="input-assignment_to">Assign to</label>
             <select class="form-control select2-single" id="assignment_to" name="assignment_to" data-placeholder="Select an user" required=""></select>
       </div>
       ...
      </div>
     </form>
    </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

It could be the modal-dialog-centered that is messing things up for you

Comment: I have tried to remove it, but it's still unscrollable!